# Rsync with a list of variables

Tags: bash, rsync

I am trying to write a bash script that will rsync only a specific subset of folders.  I am trying to figure out a more slick so that I can just add a variables such as `FOLDER1='name of folder in home directory'` and then

```
rsync -arvz --delete /home/emka/$FOLDER1/ /home/emka/Desktop/Mount/$FOLDER1
```

Currently I have `FOLDER1` through `FOLDER13`, but I do not want to have the above line thirteen times.

Could someone give me a push on how to do this?

Comment: Not a general answer to your question: But in this particular example you could also just use wildcards: `rsync -arvz --delete /home/emka/{folder1,folder2,folder[3456]} /home/emka/Desktop/Mount/`. Note the nested wildcards. And note how the trailing slashes`/` had to change.

Answer (score 3):

Bash allows you to use [arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) and [loops](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html).

Define each path as an element of an array, then loop through the array.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know this.  I'm quite new to bash.

Comment: Shell scripting is dang blasted fun! You'll like it more and more the more you use it.

Comment: there is no need to loop through the array in such simple case where one rsync command can do all work

Answer (score 1):

Some people here don’t seem to have read the original question properly, but as one suggested: you can (and should) use arrays. If you really have the folder names stored in the variables `FOLDER1`, `FOLDER2`, etc., and want to keep it that way, you can use the following:

```
for i in {1..13}; do
   eval "FOLDER=\$FOLDER$i"
   rsync -arvz --delete "/home/emka/$FOLDER/" "/home/emka/Desktop/Mount/$FOLDER"
done
```

Using quotation marks is a good habit, and in this case they are required, since you have spaces in the directory names.

Comment: If you do **rsync dir1 dir2/** then dir1 contents will be in dir2/dir1 anyway. You do not need to use "for" command for that as long $FOLDER name is the same on both side. {1..13} is brace expansion that is evaluated **before** variable name i.e. $FOLDER{1..13} will be list of $FOLDER1, $FOLDER2, … $FOLDER13 anyway

Answer (score 0):

Bash 3.0+ supports range arrays.

```
for i in {1..13}
do
    rsync -arvz --delete /home/emka/FOLDER${i}/ /home/emka/Desktop/Mount/FOLDER${i}
done
```

Comment: ach. I read it as meaning you had 13 folders called Folder1 - Folder 13. Carry on!

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash brace expansion you can just do this:

```
rsync -arvz --delete /home/emka/$FOLDER{1..13} /home/emka/Desktop/Mount/
```

If you want to use arrays (as some people suggest and which is good idea) then it is still possible to use one rsync without loop as long as folder names in array do not end with slash.

```
cd /home/emka
rsync -arvz --delete ${folderarray[@]} /home/emka/Desktop/Mount/
```

Put "echo" in the beginning of this line to see what it is going to do before first use :-)